# Swift 2.0 Sorting Array of Objects by Property

Tags: ios, swift, sorting, swift2

In Swift 2.0, how would you go about sorting an array of custom objects by a property? I know in Swift 1.2, this was done using sorted() and sort(). However, these methods no longer work in Xcode 7 beta 4. Thanks!

For example:

```
class MyObject: NSObject {
    var myDate : NSDate
}

...

let myObject1 : MyObject = MyObject() //same thing for myObject2, myObject3

var myArray : [MyObject] = [myObject1, myObject2, myObject3] 

//now, I want to sort myArray by the myDate property of MyObject.
```

Comment: There is always the bubble sort.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

In Swift 2:

- You can use `sort` method, using `compare` to compare the two dates:

  ```
  let sortedArray = myArray.sort { $0.myDate.compare($1.myDate) == .OrderedAscending }  // use `sorted` in Swift 1.2
  ```
- Or, if you want to sort the original array, you can `sortInPlace`:

  ```
  myArray.sortInPlace { $0.myDate.compare($1.myDate) == .OrderedAscending }  // use `sort` in Swift 1.2
  ```

---

In Swift 3:

- to return a sorted rendition of the array, use `sorted`, not `sort`

  ```
  let sortedArray = myArray.sorted { $0.myDate < $1.myDate }
  ```
- to sort in place, it's now just `sort`:

  ```
  myArray.sort { $0.myDate < $1.myDate }
  ```

And with Swift 3's `Date` type, you can use the `<` operator.

Comment: Example for Sorting Strings 
let myArray = ["Zen", "Step 12", "Apple"]
let sortedArray = myArray.sort({ x, y in
    return x.localizedStandardCompare(y) == NSComparisonResult.OrderedAscending
})

dump(sortedArray)

Comment: The Swift 3 rendition works fine. I suspect there's something else wrong with your code. If you're still having problems, post your own, new question on Stack Overflow with [reproducible example of your problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 10):

If you want to sort original array of custom objects. Here is another way to do so in **Swift 2.1**

```
var myCustomerArray = [Customer]()
myCustomerArray.sortInPlace {(customer1:Customer, customer2:Customer) -> Bool in
        customer1.id < customer2.id
    }
```

Where `id` is an Integer. You can use the same `<` operator for `String` as well.

You can learn more about its use by looking at an example here:
[Swift2: Nearby Customers](https://github.com/HannyTufail/Swift2-Nearby-Customers)

Comment: This can be even shorter too I think. Using $0 and $1

Answer (score 0):

**In swift 3.0**

I have taken the assumption same as the example asked in the question.

i.e customObject is MyObject with variable myDate. The array of the MyObject is myArray.We can sort like this simply.

```
myArray.sort(by: { (one: MyObject, two: MyObject) -> Bool in
    one. myDate < two. myDate
})
```

Answer (score -2):

sort is now sortInPlace (or something similar) with the same parameters as sort.