# Immutable value of type '[String]' only has mutating members named 'sort'

Tags: xcode, swift

Reading Apple's Swift guide, more specifically the **Closures** chapter I've stumbled upon a problem. A String array is declared

```
var names = ["Cris", "Alex", "Ewa", "Barry", "Daniella"]
```

The purpose of this section is to pass an array of Strings (the one above) and with the function sort(_:) have the same array back but sorted using an auxiliary method by providing a closure. The closure is the method backwards

```
func backwards(s1: String, s2: String) -> Bool {

    return s1 > s2
}
```

Then an array, reversed, is declared and applied the method sort to the original array, names:

```
var reversed = names.sort(backwards)
```

AFAIK reversed should be inferred as an array of Strings but when I check it is inferred as *var reversed: <>*. Now, *reversed* doesn't store anything and an error pops up:

```
Immutable value of type '[String]' only has mutating members named 'sort'
```

Later on in the chapter the closure is simplified a lot but I get the same error as now so I tried to fix it when the expression is simple enough but I have no clue on what to do.

I don't know if the book forgot something or is my mistake, help will be appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: `sort` doesn't create a new sorted array, but mutates the original one, which in this case cannot be mutated since you decleared it as a constant with the `let` keyword.

Comment: Done that, now names is a variable. But when I declare *var reversed* a warning pops up saying *Variable 'reversed' inferred to have type '()', which may be unexpected*.

Comment: yes, because, `sort` doesn't return anything. If you want to store the sorted array in the variable `reversed`, you should just do: `names.sort(backwards)` then `var reversed = names`, but in this case `names` and `reversed` will contain the same elements.

Comment: hmm, now it works. What I don't know is why in the book does it like the code above and it works. Thank you!

Comment: Dude theres a difference between `sort` method of array and `sorted` global method. Please checkout book again

Comment: Beware that with Swift 2 (Xcode 7) methods have changed. No more global functions, `sorted` becomes `sort` and the old `sort` becomes `sortInPlace`. http://stackoverflow.com/a/31729654/2227743