# How do you sort an array by an "updated order" date property?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, sorting

I have a class that includes an "updated order" property, and an array containing instances of that class. I want that array to be sorted based on the updated order of each of its elements. How can I do that?

Comment: Do you mean "the objects in my array have a date property that marks when they were last updated; I want the array to be sorted by that date"?

Comment: May be you are looking something similar to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31729654/2955078)

Answer (score 0):

Following OP's clarification of what they want, they have a class or struct similar to this:

```
struct CustomObj {
    var title: String
    var date: NSDate
}
```

…and they looking to sort an array of such instances based on the `date` property. Here's how it's done:

```
array.sortInPlace { (obj1, obj2) -> Bool in
    return obj1.date.compare(obj2.date) == NSComparisonResult.OrderedAscending
}
```

You can test that it works using some example data:

```
array.append(CustomObj(title: "Testing 1", date: NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: 5000)))
array.append(CustomObj(title: "Testing 2", date: NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: 2000)))
array.append(CustomObj(title: "Testing 3", date: NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: 4000)))
array.append(CustomObj(title: "Testing 4", date: NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: 3000)))
array.append(CustomObj(title: "Testing 5", date: NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: 1000)))

print(array)
```

That will order the items 5, 2, 4, 3, 1.